# Retrieve database data using PHP and AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to retrieve data from database using AJAX without any success. These are the codes I am using. I dont see any specific errors in console.

HTML:

```
<button type="button" name="result_submit" id="result_submit" >Submit</button>
<div class="result" id="result" name="result"> </div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#result_submit').click(function() {

        $.ajax({
            url  :"Income.php",
            type :'POST',
            success: function(data){
                $("#result").html(data);
            }
        });
    }); 
});
```

Income.php content:

```
<?php

include_once 'dbConnection.php';

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

$income = "select SUM(amount) as incomeNumber FROM wp_formdata WHERE entry_type='Income'";

    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$income)) 

        {
            $message =  '<h1 style="color:red;padding-top:5%;">SQL Error !!</h1>';
        } 
        else 
        {
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $result= mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            $income_sum=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
            $TotIncome= "Total Income is ".$income_sum['incomeNumber'];
        }
?>
```

dbConnection.php has connections details:

```
<?php

$dbServername = "localhost";    
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName = "wordpress";

$conn= mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

?>
```

Can someone guide me how to resolve the issue

Comment: You just need to `echo` your data from your PHP file.

Comment: write `echo $TotIncome;exit();` and it will work

Comment: echo is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `echo` your data from your PHP file :

```
$income = "select SUM(amount) as incomeNumber FROM wp_formdata WHERE entry_type='Income'";
$response = '';

if (! mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$income)) {
     $response = '<h1 style="color:red;padding-top:5%;">SQL Error !!</h1>';
} else {
     mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
     $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
     $income_sum = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
     $response = "Total Income is ".$income_sum['incomeNumber'];
}

echo $response;
```

Comment: No luck with it. I dont see any errors also in console

Comment: Try to call your Income.php directly in your navigator. It must echo the response.

Comment: It looks like button click function $('#result_submit').click(function() not triggering. I tried to put a alert box but not getting any output

Comment: do I need to add an onclick function along with button and change jquery ?

Comment: Found the issue. I mentioned complete path of  Income.php and its working as expected. I saw some thread on how to use url on wordpress site. thanks for you r help

Answer (score 0):

First off all add on the beginig of page:

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

and 
printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($income_sum));

afther query to db.
Do you have any respons from the page called by ajax?

Answer (score -1):

The script that you call using AJAX doesn't render anything.

```
echo $TotIncome;
```

Comment: its already given in comment so why you should use as answer.if you have different things than write here

Comment: SO is a question/answer website. A comment is not an answer, it is useful if you need aditionnal infos to solve the problem. If you know the solution, just post an answer...